# MyBatis multiple resultsets with procedure

Tags: java, sql, database, mybatis, ibatis

i tried the following mapping:

```
<select id="getRequestDetail" statementType="CALLABLE" parameterType="test.domain.RequestDetailRequest" resultMap="ExternalManagersMap, SubjectServicesMap">
    {call pop.dbo.getRequestDetail ( #{uid, mode=IN, jdbcType=VARCHAR},
                            #{requestId, mode=IN, jdbcType=INTEGER},
                            #{resultStatus, mode=OUT, jdbcType=INTEGER},
                            #{resultMsg, mode=OUT, jdbcType=VARCHAR} )}
</select>


<resultMap type='test.domain.User' id="ExternalManagersMap">
        <result property="name" column="externalManager"/>
</resultMap>

<resultMap type='test.domain.Service' id="SubjectServicesMap">
        <result property="name" column="serviceName"/>
        <result property="id" column="serviceId"/>
</resultMap>
```

But I have error:

> org.apache.ibatis.exceptions.TooManyResultsException: Expected one result (or null) to be returned by selectOne(), but found: 2

My interface is:
`Map<String, Object> getRequestDetail(RequestDetailRequest detailRequest);`

Can you please help me howto map multiple resutlset with calling procedure?
My DB is Sybase.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

sqlSession.selectOne indicates you are only expecting one row returned from the procedure.

Instead you should use sqlSession.select

Answer (score 0):

Method named `getRequestDetail` must be changed return type to `List<List<?>>` instead of `Map<String, Object>`.

And then, you can get a result type of List. 
It contains type of `ExternalManagersMap` in index 0 as List and type of  `SubjectServicesMap` in index 1 as List.

So, you can write like this.

```
List<List> result = getRequestDetail(RequestDetailRequest detailRequest);
ExternalManagersMap external = (ExternalManagersMap) result.get(0);
SubjectServicesMap subject = (SubjectServicesMap) result.get(1);
```